# Combine o/p of query and Stored Procedure into 1 output

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns 2 columns (`Name`, `Age`) and I have a stored procedure which returns  2 columns (col `C` & `D`).

Is it possible to combine them together so that I get a output of 4 columns i.e `Name`, `Age`, col `C`, Col `D`?

Query

```
SELECT Name, Age 
FROM "Star"."Table1" 
WHERE Id = $P{Id}
```

Stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP1]
        @Id = $P{Id}
```

Output format: `Name, Age, Col C, Col D`

Comment: How do you know which rows of `Name` and `Age` to "combine" with rows of `C` and `D` ??

Comment: is `$P{Id}` some substitution from a host language?

Comment: @marc_s, both of them return a single row of output

Comment: @Laurence, yes you are right. the parameter is provided by the Jasper tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to put the output of the stored proc into a temp table.  i.e.

```
Create table #output (Col_C varchar(100), col_D varchar(100));

Insert into #output
Exec dbo.sp1 @Id = $P{Id}

    SELECT Name, Age 
    FROM "Star"."Table1" 
    WHERE Id = $P{Id}

CROSS JOIN 

    SELECT * FROM #output
```

Comment: what is the impact if I run this query several times?

Comment: @NileshNaik do you mean for different Ids?  It should have minimal impact performance-wise, but it is not the best way to get a set of results for different ids)

Comment: yes, I meant for different IDs. Does it create a new table everytime for diff ID. What is the # before the output signify? Sorry, I am very new to SQL server

Comment: #output is called a temp table, it is a real table that exists in tempdb for the duration of the connection.  It would be a good practice to also add DROP Table #output at the end of the statement, then you do not need to worry about errors or existing data when you rerun the statement